# jQuery Validate not working - no errors?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

I've got a donation form on a website that I'm trying to validate. I found a few examples of validation online and implemented it to the form but nothing happens, and there aren't any errors generated from it.

here is all the code I have (jquery is pulled into the page as well):

```
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="donateForm" method="post">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
    <p><strong>Make your donation in memory, honour or in celebration of someone:</strong></p>

    <div class="showhideradios">
       <input name="In Honor/Memory Of" type="radio" value="No"> <label>No Thanks</label><br>
       <input id="others" name="In Honor/Memory Of" type="radio" value="In Memory"> <label>In Memory</label><br>
       <input id="noticeweeks" name="In Memory Note" style="display: none;" type="text" value=""> <input id="others1" name="In Honor/Memory Of" type="radio" value="In Celebration"> <label>In Celebration</label><br>
       <input id="noticeweeks1" name="In Celebration Note" style="display: none;" type="text" value=""></div>


    <input id="others2" name="radio2" type="checkbox" value="Attach A Meessage"> <label>Attach a message:</label> <!-- extra input, just hidden -->           <textarea id="noticeweeks2" name="Attached Message" style="display: none;" type="text" value=""></textarea></div>

    <hr>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <label>Name:</label><input name="Name" required="" type="text" value=""> 
       <label>Email:</label><input name="Email" required="" type="text" value=""> 
       <label>City:</label><input name="City" required="" type="text" value=""> 
       <label>Postal Code:</label> <input name="Postal Code" required="" type="text" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6"> 
       <label>Phone #:</label> <input name="Phone" required="" type="text" value=""> 
       <label>Street and Apt #:</label> <input name="Street and Apt #" required="" type="text" value=""> 
       <label>Province :</label> <input name="Province" required="" type="text" value=""> 
       <label>Amount (Canadian Dollars):</label> <input name="Amount" required="" type="text" value=""> 
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><input name="terms" required="" type="checkbox">
    <p>I agree to the <a href="/donations/" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a></p>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

Validation code:

```
<script>
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("cdnPostal", function(postal, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || 
    postal.match(/[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z](-| |)[0-9][a-zA-Z][0-9]/);
}, "Please specify a valid postal code.");
    jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#donateForm').validate({
        rules: {
            Name: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 2,
                lettersonly: true
            },
            Email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            City: {
                required: true
            },
            Postal Code: {
                required: true,
                cdnPostal: true
            },
            Phone: {
                required: true,
                phoneUS: true
            },
            Street and Apt #: {
                required: true
            },
            Province: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 24
            },
            Amount: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            Name: {
                required: "Please enter your name",
                minlength: "Name should be more than 2 characters",
                maxlength: "Name should be less than 20 characters",
                lettersonly: "Name should contain only letters"
            },
            Email: {
                required: "Please enter a valid email address"
            },
            City: {
                required: "Please enter a city"
            },
            Postal Code: {
                required: "Please enter a valid postal code"
            },
            Phone: {
                required: "Please enter a valid phone number"
            },
            Street and Apt #: {
                required: "Please enter your address"
            },
            Province: {
                required: "Please enter a province"
            },
            Amount: {
                required: "Please enter a Donation Amount"
            }
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

What am I missing? It would be helpful if there were errors but alas there are not.

Thank You!

Comment: You may want to try using the actual CDN links.  They're listed here:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/#1-13-1-files-on-microsoft-s-ajax-cdn-(hotlinking-welcome):

Comment: You do have JavaScript console errors.  You have keys that contain spaces in their names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It would be helpful if there were errors but alas there are not.

Yes, you do have console errors.  One JavaScript error says that a `:` is expected after `Postal`.

```
Postal Code: {
    required: true,
    cdnPostal: true
},
```

and here after `Street`...

```
Street and Apt #: {
    required: true
},
```

You must [enclose those particular names in quotes because they contain special characters](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)).  In this case, a space is also considered a special character since it breaks the `key` in the object literal's `key:value` pairs.  *(IMO, using a space within the `name` attribute is **very** unusual in any case.)*

```
"Postal Code": {
    required: true,
    cdnPostal: true
},
```

and...

```
"Street and Apt #": {
    required: true
},
```

**DEMO:  [http://jsfiddle.net/ygokv3a7/](http://It%20would%20be%20helpful%20if%20there%20were%20errors%20but%20alas%20there%20are%20not.)**

---

**NOTES:**

- IMO, special characters or spaces within the `name` attributes is not a good idea.
- You should also use [the official CDN links listed here](http://jqueryvalidation.org/#1-13-1-files-on-microsoft-s-ajax-cdn-(hotlinking-welcome)), rather than leeching from the developer's web hosting.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know very much about jquery (obviously ha ha) I didn't know there shouldn't be spaces, but what you did worked great, so thank you!

Comment: @user2596635, the issue with spaces has to do with JavaScript.  I think it would be best to edit the `name` itself to remove the spaces and special characters... your code will follow more standard practices and be easier to maintain.